# When Memory is Allocated to Class?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
Class Sample
{
  int a,b;
 public :
  Sample(int p,int q)
   {
     a=p;
     b=q;
   }
  int sum()
  {
    return (a+b);
  }
};
int main()
{
  Sample sm(10,20);
  std::cout<< "Sum :"<< sm.sum()<<endl;
}
```

I am beginner to C++ so please keep language of your answer simple so that I understand well .
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Here is a good resource: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

Comment: A `class` is the _type_ of an object. For most purposes it's like a category, which only exists at compile time, and doesn't require any storage at runtime. _Instances_ of that class - objects - do require storage, and that works as in the cppreference page linked above. (The code of a class's functions, and some other stuff, is stored in memory at runtime, but it never changes unless you re-compile).

Comment: There is no dynamic memory allocation in your sample.

Comment: @George I am asking for above class . correct me if i ask something wrong .

Answer (score 1):

The only memory allocated for a class is for static member variables. Your example doesn't contain any static member variables.

Memory is allocated for *objects*. You create one such object, in the line:

```
Sample sm;
```

This memory will go away at the end of the block where the variable is declared, when it goes out of scope.

Comment: so what I understand is Memory is allocated for Class object only , not for a class . And Memory is Allocated to class only if it has Static Member .

Comment: *"This memory will go away at the end of the block where the variable is declared"* - Not necessarily. You can bind a function's return value to reference-to-const and prolong the lifetime outside its scope. Anyway, poor questions probably should not be answered.

Comment: In this case no memory is used until an instance of the class definition is made on the line that says:   Sample sm(10,20);

Comment: Don't say "class object."  Just say "the class."  If you get used to saying "class object," it will come back to bite you when you start programming in some language like Java that has _reflection_.